# Python 2.7, How can I get/check the size of a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, if-statement, python-2.7

I've got an array (list) that I want to check if it's size is equal to 1, if it is then it needs to append a new like as shown.

```
## If appended data = 1 then append the new line:
if appended_data == 1:
    appeneded_data.append("") ## Add a new line if appended data has a size of 1
```

Should be a fairly simple thing but I can't work it out :S

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`len()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) on it:

```
if len(appended_data) == 1:
```

Short demo:

```
>>> len([])
0
>>> len([1])
1
>>> len([1, 2])
2
```